how can I show this just using the squeeze theorem and no series expansions
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k!}{n!} = 1
$$
I tried looking in this site but I didn't find what I'm looking for.

Edit:
This is my attempt: Let $b_n=n!$. Therefore $b_n$ is strictly increasing, and $\lim_{n \to +\infty}b_n=+\infty$.
On the other hand, let $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k!$.
Then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k!-\sum_{k=1}^n k!}{(n+1)!-n!}=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{n(n!)}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n+1}{n}=1$
so by Stolz–Cesàro theorem:
$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k!}{n!}=1$.


Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

See this link

@FelixMarin Thank you I didn't take this theorem into consideration.

If $n\geq 2$, we can write
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{n!}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k!}{n!}. \tag{1}
$$
Clearly,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k!}{n!}>0. \tag{2}
$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k!}{n!}&=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n(n-1)}+\frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!} \\
&=\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right) \\
&\leq\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\underbrace{\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n-1}}_{(n-2) \text{ terms}}\right) \\
&<\frac{2}{n}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
1<\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{n!}<1+\frac{2}{n}\qquad(n\geq 2). \tag{4}
$$
Applying the squeeze theorem, we finally obtain
$$
1\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{n!}
\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)=1
$$
$$
\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{n!}=1.\qquad\square \tag{5}
$$
